# While unloading the table to s3 the database gets restarted

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload a table to S3, whenever I'm trying I would get below message.

**FATAL:  A fatal error occurred. The database will be restarted.
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.**

query= UNLOAD (' select * from public.table ') to 's3://bucket/path/in/s3/' credentials  'aws_access_key_id=####;aws_secret_access_key=####'  delimiter '\t' GZIP PARALLEL ON ALLOWOVERWRITE  NULL AS 'M15sInGValue57ring' ESCAPE ADDQUOTES;

Answer (score 1):

**NULL AS string cannot be longer than 18 characters.**

UNLOAD (' select * from public.table ') to 's3://bucket/path/in/s3/' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=####;aws_secret_access_key=####' delimiter '\t' GZIP PARALLEL ON ALLOWOVERWRITE NULL AS 'M15sInG57ring' ESCAPE ADDQUOTES;

It works !!!

Reason Why it Failed?

- Whenever null encounters while unloading, it would replace with NULL
  AS string.
- There it expects it to be lesser than 18 characters.
  Otherwise while converting, it would fail.
- So that DB restart occurs.